# Detect dragup or drag down

Tags: jquery, drag, detect

I have written the following:

```
var motion;
var yPosStart = 0;
var yPosEnd = 0;
var lastDrag;
var mouseDown = false;

function drag(){
    $("*")
    .mousedown(function() {
        $(window).unbind('mousedown');
        if( mouseDown === false ) {
            mouseDown = true;
            $(window).mousemove(function(e) {
                if( yPosStart == 0 ) {
                    yPosStart = e.pageY;
                }else{
                    yPosEnd = e.pageY;  
                }
            });
        }
    })
    .mouseup(function() {
        mouseDown = false;
        lastDrag = ( yPosStart < yPosEnd ? 'down' : 'up' );
        yPosStart = 0;
        yPosEnd = 0;
        alert( lastDrag );
        $(window).bind('mousedown');
    });
}
```

I am trying to detect a drag down or drag up, but I also want to know how far. This does not seem to be working correctly and also alerts multiple times in some instances. Can anyone advise me where I am going wrong please.

Comment: Enough with the title tagging already! And signatures! You've been here for almost 2 years...

Comment: Thanks for the cracking input...

Answer (score 0):

I went down a different approach and came up with this which works nicely

```
var dragStart = 0;
var dragEnd = 0;
var move;

function getPosition(e) { 
    e = e || window.event; var cursor = {x:0, y:0}; 
    if (e.pageX || e.pageY) { 
        cursor.x = e.pageX; 
        cursor.y = e.pageY; 
    } else { 
        var de = document.documentElement; 
        var b = document.body; 
        cursor.x = e.clientX + (de.scrollLeft || b.scrollLeft) - (de.clientLeft || 0); 
        cursor.y = e.clientY + (de.scrollTop || b.scrollTop) - (de.clientTop || 0); 
    } 
    return cursor; 
}

function dragDetected( y, d ) {
    var motion = ( y > dragStart ? 'down' : 'up' );
    dragStart = 0;
    alert(motion);
}

function dragDetect(){
    $(document).mousedown(function(e){
        if( dragStart == 0 ) {
            var cursor = getPosition(e);
            move = setTimeout(function(){dragStart = cursor.y;}, 500);
        }
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function(e){
        clearTimeout( move );
        if( dragStart != 0 ) {
            var cursor = getPosition(e);
            var diff = ( cursor.y > dragStart ? cursor.y - dragStart : dragStart - cursor.y );
            if( diff >= 30 ) {
                dragDetected(cursor.y, diff);   
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/?

It has the following events:

- http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-start - on drag start
- http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-drag - when mouse is moved during drag
- http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-stop - on drag stop

In the `start` handler you can store the x,y position, comparing it each time in the `drag` handler and `stop` handler.

Which could prove useful (as well as being tested and cross browser compatible).